# Find points which fall within specified distance to POI using Python

Tags: python, geojson, point, geopandas, shapely

I have created a test shapefile containing 15 point features in EPSG:2157 and exported it geojson. Each point has been assigned an ID - e.g. 1, 2 ,3 , etc.  They look like so:
[image]

I now want to use Python to essentially create a bit like the `Select by Location` tool in ArcGIS Pro https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-location.htm

So for example the script would work like:

- Specify the ID of the point of interest
- Add a search distance in metres
- Print the ID's of the points within the specified distance and their total distance from the point of interest

I have tried this so far

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import shapely

input_file = 'C:/test/points.geojson'
df = gpd.read_file(input_file)
df['lon'] = df['geometry'].x
df['lat'] = df['geometry'].y


gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df,
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(
        df["lon"],
        df["lat"],
    ),
    crs={"init":"EPSG:2157"},
)

print(gdf)

gdf_proj = gdf.to_crs({"init": "EPSG:3857"})


x = gdf_proj.buffer(10).unary_union

neighbours = gdf_proj["geometry"].intersection(x)

# print all the nearby points
print(gdf_proj[~neighbours.is_empty])
```

But I need a way of defining which ID I want to set the 10 metre buffer from

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Programming questions here are expected to contain code. Please choose a code platform and make a coding attempt, then, if there's an issue, you can [Edit] this Question to focus on that issue.

Comment: @Vince see update

Comment: ```geopandas``` has a distance method to calculate the distance and you can sort it, apply threshold from there, and it returns a boolean array. have you used the distance method?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dataframe of one point, buffer the point and spatial join it to all other points. Spatial join is very fast.

```
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/LMV-data_2021-10/ok_riks_Sweref_99_TM_shape/oversikt/riks/gs_riks.shp')

onepoint = df.loc[df['id']==10].copy() #Select one point
onepoint.geometry = onepoint.geometry.buffer(10000)

result = sorted(onepoint.sjoin(df.loc[df['id']!=10]).id_right.tolist())
```

[image]